# How to set transition animation for content to appear?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

there is an example with content dropdown: https://codesandbox.io/s/expand-content-4pc09c?fil...
But the appearance of content on the button is quite fast. I need to set smoothness using the transition property, but it didn't work.
As far as I understand, you need to add some kind of appearance effect with the help of `visability`, but here there is a link to useState also tried to set a property for the content: `transition: all 0.5s ease-out;` but the animation is not happening
I also tried change styles like that:

```
  const styles = {
    height: expand ? "auto" : "0px",
    maxHeight: expand ? "auto" : "0px",
    overflow: expand ? "visible" : "hidden"
  };
```

but it turns out that i have the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to keep on mind various things to make it works. In your codepen there's a typo in `visibility` animation in styles.css. I attached you a working snippet but I'm explaining you some important topics about how it works.

### Explanation

First of all if you're toggling styles with you `styles` variable it'll no respect transition as it will be rendered as inline styles, so the approach I use was create a new `.wrapper__content.expanded` class and the class is the one that'll be toggled with the state.

Second about CSS properties:

- `visibility` cannot be transitioned as it doesn't have 'in-between' values, when the time of the transition (let's suppose 300ms) had passed it will change to `visible` or `hidden` with no intermediate values, that's why it cannot be 'animated'. But if you still want to add this property for accessibility purposes you can add a `transition-delay` to this property timing to trigger the change when height transition had finish.
- `height` property is a difficult one to animate because it needs explicit values to work and I recommend you not to change the `height: auto` that comes by default, as it'll be adapting to its content (avoiding overflow issues). Instead of transitioning this property you should use `max-height` in collapsed state with a value of 0 and in expanded state with a value that your content will never reach (1000px in my snippet). This will do the trick, don't forget to add `overflow:hidden;` to hide the content when it's collapsed.

I think this answer will fulfill you requirements, but any questions feel free to ask. Hope it helps.

```js
const App =() => {
  const [expand, setExpand] = React.useState(false);
  const onToggle = () => {
    setExpand(!expand);
  };

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <div className="wrapper__expand">
        <button onClick={onToggle} className="wrapper__expand-btn">
          +
        </button>
        Expand
      </div>
      <div className={expand ? 'wrapper__content expanded' : 'wrapper__content'}>
        expanded content
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.wrapper__expand {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 10px;
}

.wrapper__content {
  margin-top: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}

.wrapper__content.expanded {
  max-height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

We can really check transition using height property and somehow control the distance like that

```
transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
```

Сomment below solves my problem